# How to upgrade HP 4110 VoIP phone firmware.

Tags: upgrade, voip, lync, firmware

Actually, I have found the clue here on after googling, but the problem is I can not download the Microsoft Lync Server 2010 or 2013.

http://jackstromberg.com/2013/05/configuring-lync-server-to-push-out-latest-microsoft-lync-phone-edition-firmware/

Please kindly share me if you know how, because I am new to VoIP. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Lync 2010/2013 are replaced by Skype for Business. Therefore you couldn´t any longer find them. But as Skype for Business also offered to manage the firmware for Lync Phones you should try that one. Check here [how to use the Skype for Business device update service for connected phones](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/361-using-the-skype-for-business-device-update-service.html). You might get the latest HP 4110 VoIP phone firmware [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2636069/description-of-the-cumulative-update-for-lync-2010-phone-edition-for-hp-4110-and-hp-4120-november-2011) which you need.

---

Long answer:

**Lync 2010:**

Keep noted that [Lync 2010 already reached the end of the Mainstream Support](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/312-end-of-mainstream-support-for-lync-2010.html) as it was fully replaced by Lync 2013 (which is now replaced with Skype for Business; see below). Therefore Microsoft is pulling down the older evaluation versions (for example [Lync 2010 which was here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=145a4aaa-1f0d-403a-ad10-a1166ec44c75)) as Lync 2010/2013 is already replaced with Skype for Business.

Note: Do not get confused with Lync Server and Lync client. There is still a Trial Lync client out there ( [32bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5484) / [64bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10400) ) BUT that's not the server.

**Lync 2013:**

For Lync 2013 its mostly the same, however its not that old but was already replaced with "Skype for Business". You could get such a evaluation version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-lync-server-2013), but that link no longer works due to the reason that there is now Skype for Business.

**So the best option I think:**

Would be the Skype for business evaluation version which you can get [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-skype-for-business-server).

[image]

I personally would directly start with Skype for Business. Its mostly identically to Lync 2013 and if you know Lync 2013 you could manage as well Skype for business. You can check here [how to use the Skype for Business device update service for connected phones](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/361-using-the-skype-for-business-device-update-service.html). You might get the latest HP 4110 VoIP phone firmware [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2636069/description-of-the-cumulative-update-for-lync-2010-phone-edition-for-hp-4110-and-hp-4120-november-2011) which you need.